# UINavigationController back button title inconsistent?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I use a UINavigationController in my app and am having an issue with the back button titles. I have the title programmatically set for any page that I push to. On some of the pages the back button will correctly display the previous pages title, but then on select other pages it just says 'back'.

I have a basic implementation on pushing to a new VC:

```
- (void)pushToNewVC
{
    NewVC *newVC = [[NewVC alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
}
```

In the `viewDidLoad` of newVC/all of myVC's I have `self.title = @"Title"`.

The problem is that in some cases it works, but then in others in will just say 'Back' rather than the previous pages title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed a similar behavior that if the back button's title length won't fit in the Navigation Bar with the title of the pushed VC, the Back Button's title will fallback to just `< Back`.

On the VCs where the inconsistent behavior is happening, try setting the title of pushing VC to a shorter word just to test and confirm if that is indeed what's happening. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the issue. On the pages where all of the navigation bar content wouldn't fit it just reverted to 'back'.

Comment: Also if "< Back" doesn't fit, the button will fall back to just "<".

Answer (score 0):

Setting self.title = @"Title" will just set the title og the UINavigationBar, not the back button. Use the following code to set the back button title:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                initWithTitle: @"Back Button Text" 
                                style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                target: nil action: nil];

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];
```

Comment: The back button needs to be the title of the previous screen. Setting self.title should inherently set what the back button title is in a UINavigationController, but it's not.